# How to handle static asset generation in production?

Tags: magento2.2, deployment, static-content-deploy

I'm wondering how to handle the `setup:static-content:deploy` command in production efficiently, right now I'm running the command after `setup:upgrade` however I run into an issue where frontend assets are missing for a few seconds before the static content is finished generating.

I tried running `setup:upgrade --keep-generated` so static content doesn't get cleared, however if the static assets already exists it looks like the `setup:static-content:deploy` command ignores them and doesn't update them with new changes. As far as my tests go it seems that I need to clear the static folder so files with new changes get generated.

I know it's possible to generate assets on a build server after 2.2, so we don't have to run this process on the production server, but looking at the options this seems to rely on copying these assets manually (by adding them to source control, copying them via rsync, scp, etc).

Knowing this my main question is: is there a way to make `setup:static-content:deploy` overwrite the already existing assets with the new ones without clearing them first? This would avoid all the issues I'm having.

Comment: did you try the command setup:static-content:deploy -f ?

Comment: Yes but no help, it still skips done files if they're already generated.